# Stripe payment gateway :capture the payment on subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am using stripe subscription API to implement monthly billing on my application.

1)In the subscription API billing parameter is`charge_automatically`  so which is the proper webhook event to  capture the payment details .

2) I am setting. trialend parameter to future few minutes and set the webhook event to charge.created but it's not updating with proper value.

Comment: Do you think you could rephrase your question?  I'm not sure I am following what you mean here.

Comment: Simply which web hook event is I need to capture for the payment from the subscription